# Search line in text file and return value from a set starting point vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I'm currently using the following to read the contents of all text files in a directory into an array

```
 Dim allLines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(txtfi.FullName)
```

Within the text files are only 6 lines that all follow the same format and will read something like

forecolour=black

I'm trying to then search for the word "forecolour" and retrieve the information after the "=" sign (black) so i can then populate the below code

```
AllDetail(numfiles).uPath = ' this needs to be the above result
```

I've only posted parts of the code but if it helps i can post the rest. I just need a little guidance if possible

Thanks

This is the full code

```
Dim numfiles As Integer

    ReDim AllDetail(0 To 0)
    numfiles = 0
    lb1.Items.Clear()

    Dim lynxin As New IO.DirectoryInfo(zMailbox)

    lb1.Items.Clear()

    For Each txtfi In lynxin.GetFiles("*.txt")

        Dim allLines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(txtfi.FullName)


        ReDim Preserve AllDetail(0 To numfiles)

        AllDetail(numfiles).uPath = 'Needs to be populated
        AllDetail(numfiles).uName = 'Needs to be populated
        AllDetail(numfiles).uCode = 'Needs to be populated
        AllDetail(numfiles).uOps =  'Needs to be populated

        lb1.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(txtfi.Name))
        numfiles = numfiles + 1



    Next


End Sub

AllDetail(numfiles).uPath = Would be the actual file path
    AllDetail(numfiles).uName = Would be the detail after “unitname=”
    AllDetail(numfiles).uCode = Would be the detail after “unitcode=”
    AllDetail(numfiles).uOps =  Would be the detail after “operation=”
```

Within the text files that are being read there will be the following lines

```
Unitname=
Unitcode=
Operation=
Requirements=
Dateplanned=
```

For the purpose of this array I just need the unitname, unitcode & operation. Going forward I will need the dateplanned as when this is working I want to try and work out how to only display the information if the dateplanned matches the date from a datepicker. Hope that helps and any guidance or tips are gratefully received

Comment: I'm not sure that I have understood your problem. It is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is not very big you could simply

```
Dim allLines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(txtfi.FullName)
For each line in allLines
   Dim parts = line.Split("="c)
   if parts.Length = 2 andalso parts(0) = "unitname" Then
       AllDetails(numFiles).uName = parts(1)
       Exit For
   End If
```

Next

If you are absolutely sure of the format of your input file, you could also use Linq to remove the explict for each

```
Dim line = allLines.Where(Function(x) (x.StartsWith("unitname"))).SingleOrDefault()
if line IsNot Nothing then
    AllDetails(numFiles).uName = line.Split("="c)(1)
End If
```

**EDIT**

Looking at the last details added to your question I think you could rewrite your code in this way, but still a critical piece of info is missing.

**What kind of object is supposed to be stored in the array `AllDetails`?**

I suppose you have a class named FileDetail as this

```
Public class FileDetail
    Public Dim uName As String
    Public Dim uCode As String
    Public Dim uCode As String
End Class

....

numfiles = 0
lb1.Items.Clear()

Dim lynxin As New IO.DirectoryInfo(zMailbox)

' Get the FileInfo array here and dimension the array for the size required
Dim allfiles = lynxin.GetFiles("*.txt")

' The array should contains elements of a class that have the appropriate properties
Dim AllDetails(allfiles.Count) as FileDetail

lb1.Items.Clear()

For Each txtfi In allfiles)
    Dim allLines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(txtfi.FullName)

    AllDetails(numFiles) = new FileDetail()
    AllDetails(numFiles).uPath = txtfi.FullName

    Dim line = allLines.Where(Function(x) (x.StartsWith("unitname="))).SingleOrDefault()
    if line IsNot Nothing then
        AllDetails(numFiles).uName = line.Split("="c)(1)
    End If

    line = allLines.Where(Function(x) (x.StartsWith("unitcode="))).SingleOrDefault()
    if line IsNot Nothing then
        AllDetails(numFiles).uName = line.Split("="c)(1)
    End If

    line = allLines.Where(Function(x) (x.StartsWith("operation="))).SingleOrDefault()
    if line IsNot Nothing then
        AllDetails(numFiles).uOps = line.Split("="c)(1)
    End If

    lb1.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(txtfi.Name))
    numfiles = numfiles + 1
Next
```

Keep in mind that this code could be really simplified if you start using a List(Of FileDetails)

Comment: Thanks for both your answers. I'm having trouble with the line `AllDetails(numFiles) = line.Split("="c)(1)` . The line.split part won't work as part of an array string?!. I've added the full code i'm using to the original post in case i missed some detail

Comment: You need also to explain what you want to be inserted in the other field of AllDetails. Also explain what is the objects that should be stored in the AllDetails array

Comment: I've added to the original post - thanks so much for your help

Comment: Thanks so much, that works perfectly for me. I'm on a steep learning curve with .net and my manager is comfortable with VB6 but not so much with .Net. I've read about List(of FileDetails) so i think i'll see if i can convert over at some point